# Dynamic VBA drop down list, how to call Macro instead using pvt worksheet_change

Tags: dynamic, dropdown

I wrote a small VBA code which is a dynamic drop down list, but problem is to call a Macro on each selection, with having a single sheet its easy to use Private Sub Worksheet_Change, but how to incorporate if code is creating a new sheet and drop down list?

```
Public Sub DropDownCreator()
Range("U4").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:= _
"A, B, C, D"

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$U$4" Then
    If Range("U4").Value = "A" Then
        A_Macro
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

this works fine on single sheet, but with multiple sheets and each sheet is having drop down list not working.